# C++ Reading Matrix Type Input From A File

Tags: c++, input, time-complexity, ifstream

In `C++` is it possible to read a `NxN` matrix style input from a file and assign it to a two dimensional array in a time that has asymptotic complexity better than `O(n^2)` assuming that `N` is given in the first line and other lines has a whitespace between integers ?  I can fill my array with one by one traversing the input integers which has a cost `O(n^2)`.

```
#define MAX_SIZE 1000

std::string row,temp;
std::ifstream inpfile("input.txt");
inpfile>>row;
int size=std::stoi(row);
static int M[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];

for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
   for(int j=0;j<size;++j){
        inpfile>>temp;
        A[i][j]=std::stoi(temp);
   }
}
```

I just think something like reading the `nth line` and creating the `nth row` of array (or some container) which will reduce time complexity  to `linear time` . Are there any implementations better than iterating all elements of given matrix ?

Comment: `int A[size][size];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ are declared using a compile-time constant to denote the number of entries, not a variable.

Comment: True. I have edited my question.

Comment: You still need to read N x N values to fill in the matrix, no matter how the matrix is layed out, so I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: Even if you read line by line, reading each line itself is O(N), so ultimately it is still O(N^2) whereby N is the row/col count of the matrix.

Comment: Yes reading a line is O(N) but since this line has  well formated integers can't it be possible to pass that line to a container at once?

Comment: How is the line split i.e. space or comma?

Comment: Each line contains one space between integers

Comment: Certainly, you can choose to read 1 line at a time, then for each line, parse out the N integers to put into matrix, but that will not affect the complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer which loop through O(N) where N is an int would be this however in terms of lines you will always have O(N^2) regardless. Perhaps this is the closest solution you could have.

```
int temp;
int countX = 0;
while(inFile >> temp)
{
    A[countX/size][countX % size] = std::stoi(temp);
    countX++;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like I will use this answer in my code. Thank you!